# Setting the linear velocity of a physics object from an external module in Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk, physics

I am working on a classic RPG and need some help with joystick based movement.  The player should be able to move the character in any direction with a circular pad that he moves with his thumb.  This should be familiar from FPS games where a pad controls the left/right and forward/backward movement of the character.  My code for constructing the character is this:

```
    local player = {}
    local player_mt = { __index = player }

    function player.new( --[[ parameters for player instance ]]-- )
      local newPlayer = { --[[ player attributes here ]]-- }

      newPlayer.image = display.newImage("testImage.png")

      physics.addBody( newPlayer.image, "kinematic" )

      return setmetatable( newPlayer, player_mt )
    end
```

And this is the function for moving the character (still in the same .lua file):

```
    function player:startMoving( xMotion, yMotion)
      self:setLinearVelocity( xMotion*player.speedModifier, yMotion*player.speedModifier)
    end
```

Now in my main.lua file where I am testing out all of my functions, I initialize a new player, create a circle for the joystick, add a touch event listener to it, and use that to call my move function:

```
    local physics = require("physics")
    physics.start()

    local player = require("player")

    local myPlayer = player.new( --[[player params]]-- )

    myControl = display.newCircle( 300, 300, 100 )
    myControl:setFillColor( 100, 100, 100 )
    myControl:addEventListener( "touch", controlCharacter )

    function controlCharacter( event )
      if( event.phase == "began" ) then
        x = myControl.x
        y = myControl.y
      elseif( event.phase == "moved" ) then
        myControl.x = event.x
        myControl.y = event.y
        myPlayer:startMoving( myControl.x - event.x, myControl.y - event.y )
      elseif( event.phase == "ended" ) then
        myControl.x = x
        myControl.y = y
      end
    end
```

When I run this, I get the following error:  attempt to call method 'setLinearVelocity' (a nil value).  It's like it doesn't recognize the player as a physics object, but if I change the player physics object type in the player.lua file to dynamic,

```
    physics.addBody( newPlayer.image, "kinematic" )  ___
                                                        |
    physics.addBody( newPlayer.image, "dynamic" )    <--
```

then the gravity function operates fine, it falls right off the screen.  Can anyone help me with what's going on here?

Comment: Is `local player_mt = { __intex = player }` that `intex` a typo in your actual code or just here? Where does the `setLinearVelocity` function come from?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo bringing the code over from the file.  I made it more concise for my post and made a mistake in the process.  __intex is actually __index in my code.  The setLinearVelocity function is contained in the physics library that was required in the main.lua file.

Comment: Do you call setLinearVelocity successfully in other places? How is lua supposed to find the function from the player object? Does addBody modify its index table somehow?

Comment: No, I can't even call it directly from main.lua...  I guess I'd better go figure that one out.  The setLinearVelocity function is added to the player object when physics.addBody is called.  I don't know if addBody over-writes my previous object or if it adds to it.  I'll have to research that one as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got the answer to my question.  When I initialized the player's image as a physics object, I initialized it as newPlayer.image, so when I set the linear velocity, I needed to put

```
    self.image:setLinearVelocity
```

instead of

```
    self:setLinearVelocity
```

since self.image, not self, is the physics object.